# SQL Server query taking long time to execute

Tags: sql-server

I have the below query. It currently takes 5.5 hours to execute with the results of 5,838 rows. The whole thing runs in less than 2 minutes if I remove the timestamp limiter and just run it against all the  results of the views.

I am looking for a way to make this execute faster when trying to limit the time/date range and am open to any suggestions. I can go into more detail about the datasets if needed.

```
SELECT
    m.rpp
    ,m.SourceName
    ,m.ckt AS l_ckt
    ,m.amp AS l_amp 
    ,MAX(m.reading) AS l_reading
    ,k.ckt AS r_ckt
    ,k.amp AS r_amp
    ,MAX(k.reading) AS r_reading
FROM 
    vRPPPanelLeft m 
INNER JOIN 
    vRPPPanelRight k ON (m.sourcename = k.sourcename) 
                     AND (CAST(m.ckt AS int) + 1 = CAST(k.ckt AS int))
WHERE
    m.timestampserverlocal BETWEEN '2020-10-10' AND '2020-10-12' 
    AND k.timestampserverlocal BETWEEN '2020-10-10' AND '2020-10-11'
GROUP BY
    m.rpp, m.sourcename, m.ckt, m.amp, k.ckt, k.amp
```

Comment: Casting the `ckt` columns ruins any chance of using any indexes on those columns that might help. If you can store them and `int` values in the first place, that may open possibilities for order-of-magnitude improvements.

Comment: Also, given adding the conditional on the timestamp columns is when things get slow, we need to know the exact data type for those columns.

Comment: The view creates the ckt column from a nvarchar field in another table so I am not sure if it can be made int.

The timestamp column is just a Date data type.

Comment: Does timestampserverlocal have an index?  If not, add it.

Comment: You need to inspect your execution plan to find out where the time is spent and how you might speed it up.

Comment: If you are joining views together this can lead to poor performance. I have often found that writing the correct query against the base tables will give you significantly improved performance and this is often the first and only thing you need to do. I would also consider moving the cast conditions to the Where clause so that at least the join itself can perhaps use indexes. Providing the schemas for the views/tables/indexes and a query plan would help the community provide a decent answer.

Comment: One more thing: how many total rows are we talking about in each of the source views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming m and k are views, and potentially rather complex ones and/or having GROUP BY statements.

I'm guessing that when you look at the execution plans and/or statistics, it will actually be running at least one of the views many times - e.g., one for each row in the other view.

**Quick fix**

If you are able to (e.g., it's in a stored procedure) I suggest the following process

- Creating temporary tables with the same structures as m and k (or with relevant columns for this purpose). Include columns for the modified versions of ckt (e.g., ints for both). Consider a PK (or at least clustered index) of sourcename and ckt (the int) for both temporary tables - it may help, or may not.
- Run m and k views independently, storing results in these temporary tables. Use filtering (e.g., WHERE clause on timestampserverlocal) and potentially the relevant GROUP BY clauses to reduce the number of rows created.
- Run the original SQL but using the temporary tables rather than the views, and without the need for the WHERE clause. It may still need the GROUP BY.

**Longer fix**

I suggest doing the quick fix first to confirm that the running-views-many-times is the problem.

If it does (and the issue is that the views are being run many times) one longer fix is to stop using the views in the FROMs, and instead putting it all together in one query and then trying to simplify the code.

Comment: currently these 2 views are created using information from another view and contain Max on one of the columns so Cluster indexing is not an option.  This database is recreated nightly from another database through snapshot replication.  I am looking at your suggestion of a nightly stored proceedure to ceate those 2 views a tables to help with the execution time

Comment: I mean (as part of scripts/stored procedure/etc) use a command to create a temp table with primary keys. Syntax would be similar to`CREATE TABLE #vRPPPanelLeft (sourcename nvarchar(100), ckt int, rpp int, amp decimal(10,2), reading decimal(10,2), PRIMARY KEY(sourcename, ckt))`. Then insert into this table, selecting data from the view, with WHERE clause as appropriate for dates. The idea is to a) replace the views (in this SQL command) with temp tables, and b) be as efficient as possible when creating those temp tables

Comment: On the other hand - if the data is only updated once a day, and they're used in reports multiple times during the day, then it may make sense to pre-calculate these into actual tables (rather than temporary tables) to help with reporting. If this is the case though, it may make sense to just run the original query (the 2 minute version without WHERE clauses) so that all the data is prepared and no real processing is required. It may depend on how often the views are used elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I created a job that runs after the replication of the nightly database to this sql instance.  It truncates some tables and populates the results from the views into these tables.  It decreased the execution time down from 5.5 hours to 5 seconds